# nmap script to loop over source ports

Tags: networking, scripting, nmap

I'm trying to scan a network by rotating source port and targeting one single destination port as per:

```
for source_port in `seq $start $end`
do
    nmap -sS -p $dest_port --source-port $source_port -P0 $dest_ip
done
```

the problem is that I'm launching a nmap process every time

nmap seem design to rotate destination ports easily at command line, but for source port, I cannot find a way to specify a range even by using an nmap script (don't know how to access source-port variable in the script)

anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, you may want to use a packet-crafting framework like [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/) or [PacketFu](http://code.google.com/p/packetfu/), since these will let you specify exactly what type of packets to send without requiring a new process to be launched each time.

You could also use a packet-crafting tool like [Nping](http://nmap.org/nping/), [hping3](http://www.hping.org/hping3.html), or [nemesis](http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/), but these will also require launching a new process for each probe (as far as I know).

You could do something similar in an Nmap script by using [`socket:bind`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/nmap.html#bind) to choose a source port for each [`connect`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/nmap.html#connect), but you'd have to do a lot of tweaking to get anywhere near the performance of a full Nmap port scan. First, you'd have to [parallelize it](http://nmap.org/book/nse-parallelism.html) to send more than one packet at a time, but then you might overload the target or the network and run into congestion problems. Still, it might be worth a shot with a small number (20 or so) of worker threads to speed things up.

To speed up your current method, use `-n` to skip reverse name resolution. You can parallelize it by starting some of your nmap processes in the background or by using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). You could try to reduce the number of retries with `--max-retries`, since the default maximum is 10, but a quick test here shows that with `-Pn` and a single port, Nmap only tries 2 times to reach the port. If you want to get really fancy, you can use `--initial-rtt-timeout` and `--max-rtt-timeout` since Nmap is deliberately conservative when it starts, assuming that it will send many packets and get a better idea of network conditions. Scanning one port on one host without host discovery means that it doesn't get a chance to tune itself. If you run `ping -c 10` against your target, you can use its last line of output to set these values. For example, if I see:

```
$ ping -c 10 scanme.nmap.com
PING scanme.nmap.com (74.207.244.221) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=75.0 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=75.5 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=3 ttl=56 time=73.9 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=4 ttl=56 time=75.4 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=5 ttl=56 time=74.7 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=6 ttl=56 time=78.9 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=7 ttl=56 time=73.6 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=8 ttl=56 time=79.4 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=9 ttl=56 time=74.8 ms
64 bytes from scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221): icmp_req=10 ttl=56 time=75.1 ms

--- scanme.nmap.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 73.646/75.691/79.459/1.857 ms
```

then I can set `--initial-rtt-timeout` to `avg + 4 * mdev = 83ms` to give myself a nice wide margin of 4 standard deviations around the average round trip time. Nmap's default is to wait 1000ms (1 second), so this is quite a big speedup. Set the `--max-rtt-timeout` to 10 times the initial value just in case.